# Passing list of values as parameters to a function in R

Tags: r, function

I have two lists

```
   a=expand.grid(mtry=c(8))
   b=expand.grid(usekernel=c(8), fL=c(9))
   c=expand.grid(usekernel=c(8), fL=c(9))
   list_1<- list(a,b,c)
   list_2<- list("rf","nb","nb2")
```

And I have a function as follows

```
  func(TrainData, TrainClasses,method,tune)
  if method is "rf" then tune=a, if "nb" then tune=b, nb2=c
```

Instead of writing the method and tune every time, I want to pass the lists(list_1 and list_2) and invoke the "func" function for every method.
I tried for loop, but its not giving the desired results.

Reproducible code

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
TrainData <- iris[,1:4]
TrainClasses <- iris[,5]
method<- c("rf")
tune<-expand.grid(mtry=c(8))

func<- function(TrainData, TrainClasses,method,tune )
{
 k <- train(TrainData, TrainClasses,
               method = method,
               preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
               tuneLength = 10,
               tuneGrid = tune,
               trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
 k
}

func(TrainData, TrainClasses,method, tune)
```

So, in the above function, I'm passing one method and its tune, but now I want to pass the list of methods one after the other with their respective tune instead of giving method and its tune every time, I want to execute all the 3 methods at once.
Like I said before, my list_2 contains methods and list_1 contains respective tunes.

My code:

```
 for(i in 1:3){
     tune_e=c(list(TrainData=TrainData,TrainClasses=TrainClasses),list_2[i],list_1[i])
     do.call('func',tune_e)
 }
```

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) to facilitate good answers.

Comment: "I tried for loop" - please add your code even if it doesn't work, it will help us to see the logic.

Comment: @Roland I edited my post with reproducible code and scenario.. please check

Comment: Where does `train` come from?

Comment: @Roland I'm sry, I added the library to the post, it comes from caret package

Comment: @zx8754 I added my code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me if I haven't quite grasped what you want.  Would this work?

```
list_1 <- c(a,b,c); list_2 <- c("rf","nb","nb2")
for(i in 1:3){
    func(TrainData, TrainClasses, list_2[i], list_1[i])
}
```

The problem is with the lists.  If they are simply vectors, then it should work.  Do they need to be lists for another reason?  If so:

```
list_1 <- list(a,b,c); list_2 <- list("rf","nb","nb2")
for(i in 1:3){
    func(TrainData, TrainClasses, list_2[[1]][i], list_1[[1]][i])
}
```

The double square brackets are important.

Comment: Also, why do you need to wrap the `train` function, since that is the only thing that is executed within `func`?

Comment: I updated my code in my post, I'm trying to add some more parameters and methods and post process to it if it works out

Comment: I tried you code its not giving the results as well

Comment: error :    some required components are missing: library, type, parameters, grid, fit, predict, prob

Comment: I've edited now - one problem was the list elements.  If you specify them as vectors, it is easier.  Alternatively use `list_1[[1]][i]` to extract the elements of the list.

Comment: its not working, thing is here the method(list_2) can consider one variable at a time( for example list_2= rf, then if list_1=a(mtry) , but when we are considering vectors, it clubs three values like mtry, usekernal, fL(3 variables)

Comment: but really thanks for suggestions, I'll think about it :)

Comment: Then surely the list indexing system (`list_1[[1]][i]`) should work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83530/discussion-between-maddy-and-christopher-barry).